# How to select different fields that have different values

Tags: sql, select, field

I have a table constructed like this : idproduct,field,value

I want all the idproducts that has a field='productdescription' and a value LIKE 'Keyword' and have also a field='productpackaging' that has a value LIKE 'Keyword2'

I try something like that but it doesn't work...

```
SELECT idproduct
FROM table
WHERE field='productname'
  AND value LIKE '%Keyword1%'
  AND field = 'productpackaging'
  AND value LIKE '%KeyWord2%'
```

The hard part is that an idproduct has multiple different fields that have a unique value.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: A column value can't be productname and productpackaging at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` to ensure two different values:

```
SELECT idproduct
FROM table
WHERE (field = 'productname' AND value LIKE '%Keyword1%')
  OR  (field = 'productpackaging' AND value LIKE '%KeyWord2%')
GROUP BY idproduct
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT field) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a genius !

Answer (score 1):

One way is using aggregation and conditional counts:

```
SELECT idproduct
FROM table
group by idproduct
having count(case when field='productname' AND value LIKE '%Keyword1%' then 1 end) > 0
and count(case when field = 'productpackaging' AND value LIKE '%KeyWord2%' then 1 end) > 0
```

Comment: Missing AND in HAVING clause.